# document.style.getPropertyValue vs document.defaultView.ComputedStyles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am reading through an advance JavaScript book where they elaborated about the style object and its new properties added in DOM 2. To grasp the concept I made a small comparison program to see how the `getPropertyValue` and ComputedStyles values behave. Here is the program below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Style comparison</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #myDiv2
            {
                background-color: brown;
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Comparison</h1>
        <div>
            <h2>Using getPropertyValue function - style object</h2>
            <div id="myDiv" style="background-color: blue; width:100px; border: 1px solid black"></div>
            <input type="button" value="Get property Value on inline style" onclick="getPropertyValue()">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Using documentView.getComputedStyles - DOM 2 methods</h2>
            <div id="myDiv2"></div>
            <input type="button" value="getComputedStyles" onclick="getComputedStyles()">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getPropertyValue() {

                var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

                var properties = new Array();

                for(var i = 0, len = div.style.length; i < len; i++) {

                    var propertyName = div.style[i];
                    var value = div.style.getPropertyValue(propertyName);

                    properties.push(propertyName + " " + value);
                }

                alert(properties.join("\n"));
            }

            function getComputedStyles() {

                var div = document.getElementById("myDiv2");

                var computedStyles = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(div, null);

                alert(computedStyles.backgroundColor);
                alert(computedStyles.height);

                /*for(var i=0, len=computedStyles.length; i<len; i++){

                    alert(computedStyles[i]);
                }*/
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So based on this, I do understand that we use `getPropertyValue` on inline style css to access the attributes name and values. However, `getComputedStyle` returns the attributes values that are inside a `<style>` or external style sheet.
My question now is how can I access attributes names and values using getComputedStyles like the ones I can access with `getPropertyValue`?

Edit: To better rephrase my question. So using var computedStyles = document.defaultView.getComputedStyles("myDiv2", null) I can access the attributes value of background-color like this computedStyles.backgroundColor. However, how can I access the attribute name itself? Hope it makes it clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the answer...

```
window.getComputedStyle(div, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

or

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(div, null).getPropertyValue("background-color")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems to return the same value as computedStyles.backgroundColor. It returns the values rub(value,value,value)